# Downloading saved model from Google Cloud Datalab notebook

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab, google-cloud-ml

I'm new to Google Cloud Platform. I have written my code in Cloud Datalab , and saved a model in the datalabs notebook after training it with data. I want to download the saved model in my local machine and use it for further prediction. I saved the model in local machine and tried to run predictions with it. But I got an error saying " NotFittedError: Couldn't find trained model at  ". Can anyone tell me how to get around the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you let me know how do you do prediction? Through gcloud? Also, how do you save the model? Do you call TensorFlow's tf.python.saved_model library to save it?

With gcloud, you specify model by its directory. The directory should include a "saved_model.pb" file and a few other directories. You can inspect the model dir to see if "saved_model.pb" is there.